# About partition accidently?

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

I have a removable harddisk 650G, I installed my Ubuntu on it just 40G, else 610G is NFTS type using storage something. But yesterday I careless formatting my harddisk under windows, then I want to restart my Ubuntu but it can't find system, then I used testdisk to recovery my harddisk under Ubuntu (there is the other computer), but I just can research my Linux file but it apparent it was deleted. I don't know how to recovery my Ubuntu?
I think I just formatting NFTS type, because windows can't recognize ext type, why right now I can't enter my Linux?

Comment: If you formatted the Ubuntu partition it is gone, it says it is deleted because you deleted it. You would need to find some data recovery people and pay them alot of money to even try recovering this data. Reinstall

Comment: But I think I didn't delete them, because I can see them by testdisk, and under windows it isn't impossible to delete Ubuntu because it can't recognise ext type file, So I think I just delete something like grub, it make the computer can't find system in my harddisk, I just to know how make computer to know my harddisk exsting UBUNTU. I used ext4 to install ubuntu,

Comment: You said you formatted the partition, this is deleating, if you miss spoke try this answer

Answer (score 0):

Boot to the live DVD/USB you made when you installed Ubuntu, or make a new one.

When it asks choose try Ubuntu

Then open a terminal from the desktop (ctrl+alt+T)

and run these commands one at a time

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

Now open the dash (ubuntu icon top left) and find boot repair

Run this and choose recommended repair, follow all instructions it gives you.

This will fix any Grub errors and re install it.

Reboot

[Here is the documentation on boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

NOTE if it asks install Grub to dev/sda